# Cordova ios app build error in jenkins.Fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, jenkins

We are trying to build Cordova hybrid application for iOS platform.For this we are using Jenkins to build the cordova application.Our requirement is that we have to develop hybrid application on Window's machine and push that application to GitLab.Gitlab is integrated with Jenkins and thus through GitLab's URL mentioned in Jenkins configuration,Jenkins will be accessing the source code and  building the cordova application.
Environment : Xcode 6.4

Information about my project "LogonDemo"

== Available SDKs
 [LogonDemo] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -showsdks

OS X SDKs: 
OS X 10.9                 -sdk macosx10.9
OS X 10.10               -sdk macosx10.10

iOS SDKs: 
iOS 8.4                      -sdk iphoneos8.4

iOS Simulator SDKs: 
Simulator iOS 8.4      -sdk iphonesimulator8.4

== Available schemes
 [LogonDemo] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list 
ERROR: Timeout after 10 seconds 
Information about project "LogonDemo": 
Targets:
 LogonDemo

Build Configurations: 
Debug
Release

If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

So when I am trying to build my code from Jenkins it is failing and giving me an error of 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found.Below is the error that is displayed on Jenkins console output section.

In file included from
 /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/HybridTry/workspace/LogonDemo/LogonDemo/Classes/MainViewController.m:28: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/HybridTry/workspace/LogonDemo/LogonDemo/Classes/MainViewController.h:28:9:

```
 fatal error: Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found

    #import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
```

1 error generated.

**BUILD FAILED**
The following build commands failed:

```
CompileC build/LogonDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/LogonDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MainViewController.o LogonDemo/Classes/MainViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.11vm.clang.1_0.compiler 

CompileC build/LogonDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/LogonDemo.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MainViewController.o LogonDemo/Classes/MainViewController.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.11vm.clang.1_0.compiler     
(2 failures) 

Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure 
[OS X] restore keychains as defined in global configuration 
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/security list-keychains -s
 [PostBuildScript] - Execution post build scripts.
 [PostBuildScript] Build is not success : do not execute script
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Please suggest a solution for this error.

Answer (score 1):

-> Select your in Xcode "TARGETS".
-> Go to "Build Settings" tab.

-> Make sure that the filter is set to "All" and not "Basic".

-> Search "Search Paths" -> "Header Search Paths"

-> Double click and add this path:
Xcode 6.x
add $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include

Xcode 7.x
add $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include

-> Now clean the Project and then restart the Xcode.

Able to  "Archive".

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my cordova project. Problem was really dummy:
Instead of opening `project/platforms/ios/projectName.xcodeproj` open whole directory: `project/platforms/ios/` (double click).